# Insert WooCommerce "Custom Field" in Email confirmation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i'm using Woocommerce and the "WooCommerce Email Customizer with Drag and Drop Email Builder". I created a custom field for some products called "preorder_note". Now i'm trying to insert this field in the email for the order confirmation. Can someone help me with this? I inserted this into the "custom_code.php" (where some other code already work very well):

```
$post_id = $order->ID;
$preorder_note = get_post_meta($post_id, "preorder_note");
   echo '$preorder_note';
```

"[woo_mb_custom_code type="preorder__note"]" unfortunatly that doesn't work for the mail confirmation. How can i solve this?

Greetings
Sam

Comment: means you have not getting this pre order notes in sent email?

Comment: Right. Instead of my note there is just a "$preorder_note" in the mail.

Comment: You have to remove single quote from the last line `echo '$preorder_note';` and try to this one `echo $preorder_note;`

Comment: Thanks. Now it's printing "Array" instead of my text. Any idea?

Comment: Okay You have to use this `print_r($preorder_note)` function to display the array value and then show your output value of above function

Comment: The output is:
Array ( )

Comment: can you echo $post_id? check it's return value or not?

Comment: Yes it returns the order number. I'm not sure if it's right, because my value "preorder_note" belongs to a product and not to a specific order.

Comment: Yeah that means this is not product id so you have to first find product id using the $order object

Comment: May be this function helps to find product id '$orders = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();' For more help you have to check this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97176/get-product-id-from-order-id-in-woocommerce